# Google Glass : How to back to menu items after select an item with voice triggers?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I've wrote an app which triggers with voice and the sequence is,

1. Say "ok glass"
2. Say "Testing App" (to launch my app)
3. Say "ok glass" again. (to load the menu items, I have 5 menu items with sub menu each.)
4. Say "Dining Hall" (list all the sub menu items)
5. Say "Off" (one of the sub menu)
6. Will pop up a card says the command is executed.
7. My app will then have to go through step 3 again to show the list of the menu items.

May i know is there anyway to straight list all the menu items and ready to receive another voice triggers after step 6?

Answer (score 0):

When the card pops up make sure you set your menu parameters the same as they where when started. Not sure what you are exactly doing since you're not providing any code.

but you can use this line of code to make sure your voice commands "reset"

```
getWindow().invalidatePanelMenu(WindowUtils.FEATURE_VOICE_COMMANDS);
invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

Hope that is what you're looking for